# Android Arc navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, automatic-ref-counting, drawer

I would like to do a navigation drawer like the app "Grazia"

image -> http://puu.sh/j4StR/f28f1fe3a4.jpg

Someone could advice me how to start it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some open source projects that do it:

https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu - Apache 2.0

https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu/ - LGPL